# Error on publishing promotion in SmartTarget 2014 SP1

Tags: 2013, smarttarget

I have just installed SmartTarget 2014 SP1 on the existing SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. Fredhopper 7.5 was also installed. Upgraded the existing odata and content deployer by adding smarttarget related jars as per the manual.

My fredhopper is not initialized since the DCP(with Add to SmartTarget) publishing is failing - "Please wait
The Business Manager will be available when the indices are loaded.
(This page will refresh in 10 seconds)".

I am getting "Unable to persist the Fredhopper XML, java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\fredhopper\SmartTargetIndexer\data\fas-xml-incremental\catalog01\tcm_0-91403-66560_component.tmp (The system cannot find the path specified)".

My deployment web service is up on 8080 and I can see the wsdl. Please advice me.

Log from cd_core of the deployer -

2015-02-24 09:21:21,967 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=templateid, displayName=templateid, type=list, valueId=tcm_85_48131_32, value=tcm:85-48131-32
2015-02-24 09:21:21,967 DEBUG SchemaInfoBuilder - Reading schema file: C:\tridion\incoming\dd4t\Zip\tcm_0-91403-66560.Content\Schemas\tcm_85-48134-8
2015-02-24 09:21:21,982 DEBUG SchemaInfoBuilder - Unable to find label for field 'Content' - returning field name instead.
2015-02-24 09:21:22,014 INFO  ConfigurationUtility - no publication mapping found for tcm:0-85-1
2015-02-24 09:21:22,029 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=tcm_85_48134_8_text, displayName=SmartTarget Schema - text, type=text, valueId=tcm_85_48135_tcm_85_48131_32_text_value, value=SmartTarget
2015-02-24 09:21:22,029 DEBUG SmartTargetXMLUtils - Generating FH attribute: attributeId=tcm_85_48134_8_description, displayName=SmartTarget Schema - description, type=text, valueId=tcm_85_48135_tcm_85_48131_32_description_value, value=SmartTarget 2014 installation testing
2015-02-24 09:21:22,060 WARN  CommitPhase - Failure during the post-transaction and the transaction will NOT be rolled-back
2015-02-24 09:21:22,060 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to execute onSuccess event in phase: Deployment Commit Phase for transaction: tcm:0-91403-66560
2015-02-24 09:21:22,060 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-91403-66560
**com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Failed during the post-transaction phase., Unable to persist the Fredhopper XML, java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\fredhopper\SmartTargetIndexer\data\fas-xml-incremental\catalog01\tcm_0-91403-66560_component.tmp (The system cannot find the path specified), java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\fredhopper\SmartTargetIndexer\data\fas-xml-incremental\catalog01\tcm_0-91403-66560_component.tmp (The system cannot find the path specified), Unable to persist the Fredhopper XML, java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\fredhopper\SmartTargetIndexer\data\fas-xml-incremental\catalog01\tcm_0-91403-66560_component.tmp (The system cannot find the path specified), java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\fredhopper\SmartTargetIndexer\data\fas-xml-incremental\catalog01\tcm_0-91403-66560_component.tmp (The system cannot find the path specified)**
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.onSuccess(CommitPhase.java:119) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]

Answer (score 1):

It's fixed. Actually I mentioned the path also along with the deplument webservice URL in smarttarget config for deployer which it was not able to find. Removing the location path from config fixed it.